# What is a good Pythonic way to handle complicated for loops with many functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, coding-style

I have a relatively complicated script that requires functions to be executed within a for loop and in some cases the result of one function is read into the next function.  I can handle this relatively easy with a for loop, but the execution speed is significantly less than with list comprehension.  I am not sure how to execute this problem with list comprehension.  Is there a better vectorized way to do this in python.  I am attaching an example that is significantly simpler than my actual problem, but it I think it highlights the problem.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
def func1(i):
    return i + 1

def func2(j):
    return j + 2

def func3(k):
    return k + 3

class test:
    def __init__(self, one, two, three):
    self.one = one
    self.two = two
    self.three = three

if __name__ == "__main__":

    obj = []
    for i in range(10):
        if i !=3 and i != 7:
            value1 = func1(i)
            value2 = func2(i)
            value3 = func3(value2)
            one1 = value1 + value2
            two1 = value1 + value2 + value3
            three1 = value1 + value3
            obj.append(test(one1, two1, three1))
```

Comment: `[test(func1(i)+func2(i), func1(i)+func2(i)+func3(func2(i)), func1(i)+func3(func2(i)) for i in range(10) if (i != 3 and i != 7)] ` is a simple "make this for loop into a comprehension", but also it requires calling the functions significantly more times than should be necessary so I don't think it's what you're looking for. Also, it is very inelegant.

Comment: @Edward Minnix that was a type that I just fixed

Comment: @a625993, the problem I listed here is substantially simpler than the real problem.  If I had to embed all of the functions into list comprehension it would be a gargantuan mess.  there has to be a better, more aesthetic way to do this.

Comment: List comprehensions are faster, but not that much faster.  Your code is not slow because it is using a for loop.  It's likely inefficient in some other way.  The main draw of list comprehensions is readability.  Don't try to cram too much into one.

Comment: "but the execution speed is significantly less than with list comprehension” why do you believe that? Have you times it, or are you just assuming? Because generally in my car experience list comprehensions are only marginally faster than an equivalent for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cram the inside of your loop into its own function.

```
def loop_interior(i):
        value1 = func1(i)
        value2 = func2(i)
        value3 = func3(value2)
        one1 = value1 + value2
        two1 = value1 + value2 + value3
        three1 = value1 + value3
        return test(one1, two1, three1)
```

Now the loop populating `obj` is short and sweet.  You could even use a list comprehension if you like. `obj = [loop_interior(i) for i in range(10) if (i != 3 and i != 7)]`

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if this is quite what you're looking for, but you can do it slightly more elegantly in two lines, if you first create a comprehension for values and then populate your `obj` list.

```
values = [(func1(i), func2(i), func3(func2(i)) for i in range(10) if (i != 3 and i != 7)]
obj = [test(v[0]+v[1], v[0]+v[1]+v[2], v[0]+v[1]) for v in values]
```

The downside is more memory usage, having to keep the values in memory, but this also should call each of the functions the same time as your above code. If you can create a list generator instead of a comprehension for `values`, that would speed it up further.